# Consequences of maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Q. Let $f$ be holomorphic and satisfy $|f(z)| \leq A e^{|z|^{\alpha}},$ for all Re $z \geq 0,$ and where $0<\alpha<1$. If $|f(z)| \leq M$ on the imaginary axis, and $f(1)=0,$ prove that, for $x>0$
$$
|f(x+i y)| \leq M\left\{\frac{(1-x)^{2}+y^{2}}{(1+x)^{2}+y^{2}}\right\}^{1 / 2}
$$

Here, how to apply maximum modulus principle on the imaginary axis as the boundary for right half plane and to prove $|\frac{1+z}{1-z}f(z)|\leq M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is a Möbius transformation which maps the right halfplane onto the unit disk. In particular, $|T(z)| =1$ on the imaginary axis.

For $|z| \ge 2$ is
$$
 |T(z)| \ge \frac{|z|-1}{|z|+1} = 1 - \frac{2}{|z|+1} \ge \frac 13 \, .
$$

$f(1) = 0$ so that $g(z)=f(z)/T(z)$ is holomorphic in the right halfplane and continuous on its boundary. $|g(z)| \le M$ on the imaginary axis, and
$$
 |g(z)| \le 3 A e^{|z|^{\alpha}}
$$
if $\operatorname{Re}(z) \ge 0$ and $|z| \ge 2$. Then $|g(z)| \le B e^{|z|^{\alpha}}$ for some constant $B > 0$ and all $z$ with $\operatorname{Re}(z) \ge 0$.

Now we can apply the [Phragmén–Lindelöf principle for a sector in the complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle#Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle_for_a_sector_in_the_complex_plane) to $g$ and conclude that $|g(z)| \le M$ everywhere in the right halfplane, i.e.
$$
 |f(z)| \le M \cdot \left| \frac{z-1}{z+1} \right|
$$